# Calculate 4 newest comments per post in query

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query to get posts with calculated number of likes and calculated user who created the post:

```
MATCH (post:Post)
WITH post
ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post)
RETURN post, user.username AS createdBy,
       size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS likes
SKIP {skip}
LIMIT {limit}
```

What I need is to calculate last 4 created comments for every post. If there is 0 comments, I would like to have returned empty array and there is also possibility that post has less then 4 comments, so will just show array of these comments.

I need smth like this (I added imaginary query):

```
MATCH (post:Post)
WITH post
ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post)
[MATCH (comment:Comment)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(post:Post) ORDER BY comment.timestamp ASC]
RETURN post, user.username AS createdBy,
       size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS likes,
       comment AS comments
SKIP {skip}
LIMIT {limit}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CREATED]->(post:Post)
WITH user, post
ORDER BY post.createdAt DESC
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(comment:Comment)
WITH user, post, comment
ORDER BY comment.timestamp DESC
RETURN post, user.username AS createdBy,
       size((post)<-[:LIKES]-(:User)) AS likes,
       COLLECT(comment)[0..4] AS latestComments
SKIP {skip}
LIMIT {limit}
```

It returns the posts (in descending order), and for each post it returns the creator's name, the number of likes, and a collection of (up to) the last 4 comments. It uses `OPTIONAL MATCH` to ensure that it returns posts that have no comments at all.

Comment: The problem with this query is that it shows me only posts that have at least one comment and filters out post with 0 comments. If post doesn't have any comments I want to get empty array [] for latestComments, or at least null value.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @PeterParada , Until now I thouht I can only use Neo4j only for friends level and other relations , But never thought we can use it for post,comments and users also :) I am currently using MYSQL for this , But all the combining logic is in server code . Could you please let me know how is the performance using Neo4j for this case and also how many records you have in your system ..? Thank You